# How can I make a local storage storage file for mobile app

Tags: xml, file, xamarin.forms, local-storage, cross-platform

I'm building a Xamarin CrossPlatform app all of its database is in cloud api's,
but I want a local storage file in mobile which stores all login credentials whenever someone is login.

**Kindly help me through this!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just save the login credentials you should use [Xamarin.Essentials Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android)

First, Add the Xamarin.Essentials [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/) to each project.

In Android

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState); // add this line to your code
    //...
```

To handle runtime permissions on Android, Xamarin.Essentials must receive any OnRequestPermissionsResult. Add the following code to all Activity classes:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

And then to save:

```
try
{
  await SecureStorage.SetAsync("loginCredential", "loginCredentialValue");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

To retrieve:

```
try
{
  var loginCredential = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("loginCredential");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
}
```

Comment: Thankyou soo much it works for me. One more favor if i have data more than login than what should I do ?

Comment: Depends, if you have much information, you'd better have a local database to save everything.

Comment: Sir I have Azure Cloud database but I want a local storage file which can save "username", "password", "tracking id". Is it possible  ?                                                   File like XML ?

Comment: If you only want to save that, you can use the method I provided. just create more variables

Comment: Yes! This is for android and iOS. You can check the documentation link I provided. Don't forget to upvote if it helped you :D